# Python 2.7: How to compensate for missing pool.starmap?

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have defined this function

```
def writeonfiles(a,seed):
    random.seed(seed)

    f = open(a, "w+")
    for i in range(0,10):
        j = random.randint(0,10)
        #print j
        f.write(j)
    f.close()
```

Where a is a string containing the path of the file and seed is an integer seed.
I want to parallelize a simple program in such a way that each core takes one of the available paths that I give in, seeds its random generator and write some random numbers on that files, so, for example, if I pass the 
vector

```
vector = [Test/file1.txt, Test/file2.txt]
```

and the seeds

```
seeds = (123412, 989898),
```

it gives to the first available core the function

```
writeonfiles(Test/file1.txt, 123412)
```

and to the second one the same function with different arguments:

```
writeonfiles(Test/file2.txt, 989898)
```

I have looked through a lot of similar questions here on Stackoverflow, but I cannot make any solution work. 
What I tried is:

```
def writeonfiles_unpack(args):
    return writeonfiles(*args)
if __name__ == "__main__":
     folder = ["Test/%d.csv" %i for i in range(0,4)]
     seed = [234124, 663123, 12345 ,123833]
     p = multiprocessing.Pool()
     p.map(writeonfiles, (folder,seed))
```

and gives me TypeError: writeonfiles() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given).

I tried also

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder = ["Test/%d.csv" %i for i in range(0,4)]
    seed = [234124, 663123, 12345 ,123833]
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=writeonfiles, args= [folder,seed])
    p.start()
```

But it gives me
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 120, in seed
    super(Random, self).seed(a)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Finally, I tried the contextmanager

```
 @contextmanager
 def poolcontext(*args, **kwargs):
     pool = multiprocessing.Pool(*args, **kwargs)
     yield pool
     pool.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder = ["Test/%d" %i for i in range(0,4)]
    seed = [234124, 663123, 12345 ,123833]
    a = zip(folder, seed)
    with poolcontext(processes = 3) as pool:
    results = pool.map(writeonfiles_unpack,a )
```

and it results in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 572, in get
    raise self._value

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: I think you forgot a `*` in `def writeonfiles_unpack(args)`

Comment: Actually no, you are unpacking tuple `args` to function call, sorry. But it feels a little strange

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python 2.7 lacks the `starmap` pool-method from Python 3.3+ . You can overcome this by decorating your target function with a wrapper, which unpacks the argument-tuple and calls the target function:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random
from functools import wraps


def unpack(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(arg_tuple):
        return func(*arg_tuple)
    return wrapper

@unpack
def write_on_files(a, seed):
    random.seed(seed)
    print("%d opening file %s" % (os.getpid(), a))  # simulate
    for _ in range(10):
        j = random.randint(0, 10)
       print("%d writing %d to file %s" % (os.getpid(), j, a))  # simulate


if __name__ == '__main__':

    folder = ["Test/%d.csv" % i for i in range(0, 4)]
    seed = [234124, 663123, 12345, 123833]

    arguments = zip(folder, seed)

    pool = Pool(4)
    pool.map(write_on_files, iterable=arguments)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed the write on files function to make it print the writings on actual files (with f = open(a, "w+")). It does as intended, however, if I put f.close() after the for it gives me ValueError: I/O operation on closed file; as if every core would try to use the same f...

Comment: @Francesco Di Lauro Sounds like wrong indent for `f.close()`.  Is it still like in your example? Add my 'opening file'-print back additionaly to see if it get's the right filename. Btw, you also would have to make `j` a string before attempting to write or you would get `TypeError`.