# Passing second argument to function in pool.map

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a panda dataframe with many rows, I am using multiprocessing to process grouped tables from this dataframe concurrently. It works fine but I have a problem passing in a second parameter, I have tried to pass both arguments as a Tuple but it doesn't work. My code is as follows:

I want to also pass in the parameter "col" to the function "process_table"

```
for col in cols:
    tables = df.groupby('test')
    p = Pool()
    lines = p.map(process_table, table)
    p.close()
    p.join()

def process_table(t):
    # Bunch of processing to create a line for matplotlib
    return line
```

Comment: Use `starmap` (Python 3.3+) like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53805285/9059420).  You don't need do rebuild your Pool on every iteration, create it once outside the loop and reuse it.

Comment: @Darkonaut Is there an alternative for Python 2.7?

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52671399/9059420)

Comment: @Darkonaut Thanks, I worked that one out but I am getting an error for "p" which is the pool object. After debugging for a little, it looks like the second parameter "col" which in this case is a string "pnl" comes into the helper function unwrapped as 'p' in the first iteration and then 'n', then 'l' and then I get the error

Comment: Look at my first linked answer and how to make the arguments the same length.

Comment: @Darkonaut Works great, thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 2.7: How to compensate for missing pool.starmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52651506/python-2-7-how-to-compensate-for-missing-pool-starmap)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, it takes an iterable and expands it into individual arguments :

```
def expand(x):
    return process_table(*x)

p.map(expand, table)
```

You might be tempted to do this:

```
p.map(lambda x: process_table(*x), table) # DOES NOT WORK
```

But it won't work because lambdas are unpickleable (if you don't know what this means, [trust me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348532/can-python-pickle-lambda-functions)).

Comment: Right, forgot that bit... You can use a regular function instead.